# Prove the function $f(x)=e^{-|x|^2}$ is a function in $L^p(R^n)$ and in $S(R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the function $f(x)=e^{-|x|^2}$ is a function in $L^p(R^n)$ and in $S(R^n)$

I know that a function is in $L^p$ if $(\int_{R^n} |f(x)|^p dx)^{\frac{1}{p}}<\infty$

and it's in $S(R^n)$ if $\sup_{x\in R^n}(1+|x|^N)|\partial^\alpha f|<\infty, \forall N \in Z_+, \forall \alpha \in Z^N_+$

To prove the function is in $L^p$ I calculate :

$(\int_{R^n}|e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}x_i^2}|^p dx)^{\frac{1}{p}}$=
$(\int_{R^n}|e^{-p\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}x_i^2}| dx)^{\frac{1}{p}}$=$(\int_{R}e^{-px_1^2} dx_1)^{\frac{1}{p}} $$(\int_{R}e^{-px_2^2} dx_2)^{\frac{1}{p}} $.....=
$(n\sqrt \frac{\pi}{p})^\frac{1}{p}<\infty$ so $f\in L^p$.

I have no idea how to prove it's in the Schwartz' space.

Comment: Can you do it for $\alpha =0?$

Comment: Have you see this post, for when $n=1?$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557132/how-do-you-show-that-fx-e-x2-is-in-the-schwartz-space-mathcals-bb

Comment: Is the calculus for the function in $L^p$  correct?

Comment: The post is for Schwartz functions, but Schwartz functions are in $L^p$, so it suffices to show that it's Schwartz.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. Show that if $p$ is any polynomial, then $p(x) e^{-|x|^2}$ is bounded.
2. Show, using induction on the order $N$ of $\alpha$, that every derivative $ \partial^\alpha e^{-|x|^2}$ is of the form $p(x) e^{-|x|^2}$ where $p$ is a polynomial.